# En PHP, ¿cómo generar un JSON con arreglos pero cuya salida no contenga corchetes?

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo tres resultados, el primero es el ideal, el que requiero, pero debo colocar los ítems (los vuelos) uno por uno, y así no me sirve, porque debería ser creado a través de un ciclo.

Los otros dos resultados, si lo hago por medio de ciclos, pero me muestra o en resultado hay corchetes y así no sirve.

Explicación del código:

Puede haber N vuelos, que permiten N maletas. Se quiere que por cada vuelo le indique las maletas que lleva X pasajero.

Ejemplo:

Vuelo {“9494949494_0”, {“1”:1,”2”:0}} para ese vuelo el pasajero de dos maletas permitidas solo lleva una (“1”:1).

Acá está simplificado el código PHP dado que le coloqué directamente valores de vuelo y maletas con sus respectivos array.

```
//Los vuelos
$rutatotal=3;
$idVuelo[0]="9494949494944_0";
$idVuelo[1]="9494949494944_1";
$idVuelo[2]="9494949494944_2";

//Las maletas
$total_maletas=2;
$maleta_pasajero[1]=1;
$maleta_pasajero[2]=0;

//*************************  RESULTADO 1 ****************** RESULTADO 1 
//Salida ideal, la se requiere como valida
for ($j=1;$j<=$total_maletas;$j++){
    $yyy[$j]=$maleta_pasajero[$j];

}

$ayyy=array($idVuelo[0]=>$yyy,$idVuelo[1]=>$yyy,$idVuelo[2]=>$yyy); 
//colocando de forma específica, "a pie".
echo json_encode($ayyy,true);
echo "<br>";
//Resultado No. 1: {"949494949494944_0": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, 
"949494949494444_1": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, "9494949494944_2": {"1": 1, "2 ": 0}}
//Si sirve, porque está sin corchetes, pero se debe colocar cada vuelo con 

//*************************  RESULTADO 2 ****************** RESULTADO 2 
for ($h=0;$h<$rutatotal;$h++){
$cadena[]=array($idVuelo[$h]=>$yyy);

}
echo json_encode($cadena,true);
echo "<br>";
//Resultado No. 2: [{" 9494949494944_0 ": {" 1 ": 1," 2 ": 0}}, {" 
 9494949494944_1 ": {" 1 ": 1," 2 ": 0}}, {" 9494949494944_2 " : {"1": 1, 
 "2": 0}}] 
 //No sirve, porque tiene corchetes []  

 //*************************  RESULTADO 3 ****************** RESULTADO 3 
 //***************   
 for ($h=0;$h<$rutatotal;$h++){
   $xxx[$h]=array($idVuelo[$h]=>$yyy);

 }
 echo json_encode($xxx,true);
 echo "<br>";
 //Resultado No. 3: [{" 9494949494944_0 ": {" 1 ": 1," 2 ": 0}}, {" 
 //9494949494944_1 ": {" 1 ": 1," 2 ": 0}}, {" 9494949494944_2 " : {"1": 1, 
 //"2": 0}}] 
 //No sirve, porque tiene corchetes []
```

Comment: Has probado a poner en el ejemplo 2 y 3 esto: echo json_encode($cadena[0],true);

Comment: No he probado, voy a ver. Gracias.

Comment: Una enumeración del tipo `$cadena[] = array($idVuelo[$h]=>$yyy);` siempre devolverá un resultado con corchetes a no ser que uses [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir el JSON que necesitas sin conocer de antemano el contenido de las matrices que contienen las maletas y vuelos y generar el JSON correcto necesitas:

- Iterar por las matrices con `foreach`.
- Asignar tus datos al índice adecuado.
- Eliminar el `true` que es convertido a la constante `1` (`JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY`).

El código para reproducir y corregir tu problema ha sido:

```
<?php
// Los vuelos (ya no es necesario conocer el número de ellos)
//$rutatotal = 3;
$idVuelo[0] = "0438754234344";
$idVuelo[1] = "9843652123665";
$idVuelo[2] = "3232434343423";
$idVuelo[3] = "5454353453454";

// Las maletas (tampoco es necesario conocer el número)
//$total_maletas = 2;
$maleta_pasajero[1] = 1;
$maleta_pasajero[2] = 0;

// Basado en tu ejemplo "RESULTADO 1"
// Iteramos por cada elemento de $maleta_pasajero obteniendo su índice y contenido
foreach ($maleta_pasajero as $j => $valor) {
  $yyy[$j] = $valor;
}

/* Genero la base de $ayyy */
$ayyy = [
  'hold_bags' => [ ],
];

/* Vamos vuelo por vuelo agregando las maletas a cada uno */
foreach($idVuelo as $valor) {
  // ¿No sería lo mismo que: $ayyy['hold_bags'][$valor] = $maleta_pasajero ?
  $ayyy['hold_bags'][$valor] = $yyy;
}

/* No uso como parámetro "true" (JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY) */
echo json_encode($ayyy, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), PHP_EOL;
```

El resultado de ejecutar ese código será:

```
{
    "hold_bags": {
        "0438754234344": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 0
        },
        "9843652123665": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 0
        },
        "3232434343423": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 0
        },
        "5454353453454": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Sin `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`:

```
{"hold_bags":{"0438754234344":{"1":1,"2":0},"9843652123665":{"1":1,"2":0},"3232434343423":{"1":1,"2":0},"5454353453454":{"1":1,"2":0}}}
```

Puede consultarse la respuesta original en la que propongo formas de convertir los corchetes en llaves al generar el JSON en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/242050/3).

Comment: Muchas gracias Oscar, pero los indices "0","1", etc. No son válidos. Es una petición a una API, y debe ser tal cual como el "Resultado 1", sin corchetes, sin indices.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo válido en tu pregunta? Hay uno de los ejemplos que está cortado. Pone "Si sirve, porque está sin corchetes, pero se debe colocar cada vuelo con" y ahí se corta.

Comment: Por cierto, en esa línea usas `json_encode($ayyy, true);` que carece de sentido porque `true` no es un parámetro válido de `json_encode()`. Debes usar las constantes que te enlacé o bien `true` será convertido a entero y, por lo tanto, usada la constante `1` ([`JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/623911f993f39ebbe75abe2771fc89faf6b15b9b/ext/json/php_json.h#L57)).

Comment: //Salida ideal, la se requiere como valida
for ($j=1;$j<=$total_maletas;$j++){
        $yyy[$j]=$maleta_pasajero[$j];
        
    }
   
   $ayyy=array($idVuelo[0]=>$yyy,$idVuelo[1]=>$yyy,$idVuelo[2]=>$yyy); //colocando de forma específica, "a pie".
   echo json_encode($ayyy,true);
   echo "<br>";
   //Resultado No. 1: {"949494949494944_0": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, "949494949494444_1": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, "9494949494944_2": {"1": 1, "2 ": 0}}
   //Si sirve, porque está sin corchetes, pero se debe colocar cada vuelo con las maletas

Comment: "hold_bags": {
        "341202495": {
          "1": 1,
          "2": 1,
          "3": 0
        },
        "341214132": {
          "1": 1,
          "2": 1,
          "3": 0
        }
      }

Comment: Me refiero a que pongas un ejemplo del JSON válido. Cuando dices "se debe colocar cada vuelo con las maletas" no entiendo qué resultado se espera.

Comment: Ahh, ahora sí :) Cambiando mi respuesta.

Comment: Salida correcta: {"949494949494944_0": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, "949494949494444_1": {"1": 1, "2": 0}, "9494949494944_2": {"1": 1, "2 ": 0}}

Comment: El problema está a la hora de generar los datos, he de cambiar todo el código de mi respuesta. Por favor, espera a que te diga que he terminado en un nuevo comentario, ignora esta edición intermedia.

Comment: Ahora sí. ¿Podrías comprobar si esto es lo que andas buscando?

Comment: Oscar quiero darte de verdad las gracias por el tiempo que te haz tomado, efectivamente la salida es correcta. El inconveniente está en que nunca se sabe cuantos vuelos pueden ser, es por ello que pretendo hacerlo con ciclos, al hacerlo así: $idVuelo[0] => $yyy,  estamos colocando uno a uno los vuelos, al igual que lo hice yo en el "resultado no. 1", en los otros dos resultados pretendo hacerlo con ciclos, para N vuelos. Pero sale corchetes. Ojala me haya explicado bien.

Comment: Vale, entonces déjame hacer una nueva edición para mostrarte cómo hacer bucles correctamente sin necesitar las variables `$rutatotal` o `$total_maletas`.

Comment: Ya tienes una nueva edición. Espero que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Correcto Oscar, esa es la respuesta. Muchas gracias! Éxitos!